# Why am I getting this error message in JSX - x Expression expected?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm receiving errors stating - x Expression expected and Unterminated regexp literal...[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgYx7.png)

The code I'm having issues with is the following:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';
import {useContext} from "react";
import {UserContext} from "../lib/context";

// Top Navbar
export default function Navbar() {
    const { user, username } = useContext(UserContext)

    return (
        <nav className='navbar'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link href="/">
                        <button>FEED</button>
                    </Link>
                </li>

                {/* user is signed in and has username */}
                {username && (
                    <div>
                        <li className='push-left'>
                            <Link href="/admin">
                                <button className="btn-blue">Write Posts</button>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link href={`/${username}`}>
                                <img src={user?.photoURL} alt=/>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                )}


                {/* user is not signed in OR has not created username */}
                {!username && (
                    <li>
                        <Link href="/enter">
                            <button className="btn-blue">Log in</button>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check line 29. `<img src={user?.photoURL} alt=/>`

The alt tag should contain at least an empty string:

`<img src={user?.photoURL} alt=""/>`

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solved it by switching to double quotes instead of single quotes in the HTML/CSS.